# rookie help with NHibernate ASP.NET (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to get my head around NHibernate, I've run through this tutorial
http://www.codegod.de/WebAppCodeGod/NHibernate-Tutorial-1---and-ASP-NET-AID25.aspx

My problem is that I cannot compile my code (just pasting the tutorial code into a new MVC 2 web app) because of an unknown reference to SessionHelper in NHibernateHttpModule?

Can anyone suggest how to get this working?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well that your question is a bit vague but I would try a couple of things (btw, I'm not assuming anything about your project beyond your copy and paste job)

1. Make sure you download, add references, and `using` statements to the newest nhibernate libraries in your MVC project.  This includes NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.dll, NHibernate.dll, Iesi.Collections.dll, and FluentNHibernate.dll for Fluent NHibernate.
2. Look for a more recent tutorial. The one you're referencing is ancient and may not even work with MVC2.  Here's a start: [Using ASP.NET MVC and NHibernate](http://forerunnerg34.wordpress.com/2009/11/03/using-asp-net-mvc-and-nhibernate-part-1/)